# MySQL SELECT multiple rows with same column value based on value from another column

Tags: mysql

I am just getting started with MySQL queries, and have been fighting this for days with no luck finding a solution, so here goes.

Table structure as follows:

```
|         ID         |   TAG
| 111909684134416384 | WesternU
| 111909684134416384 | ldnon
| 111910470428008448 | ldnont
| 111910470428008448 | fb
| 111910605249712128 | LTC
| 111910605249712128 | ldnon
| 111911886139826176 | ldnont
| 111911886139826176 | WesternU
```

I would like to select, count, and list the TAG(s) where one TAG of the same ID has 'ldnont' or 'ldnon' listed.

Essentially, from this data set, I would like to list and count:

```
WesternU (2)
fb (1)
LTC (1)
```

I've been able to select and count, but only the first row of rows with duplicate ID.
Thank-you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT Tag, COUNT(*) FROM JodyTable 
      WHERE Tag NOT IN ('ldnon', 'ldnont')
         AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM JodyTable WHERE Tag IN ('ldnon', 'ldnont'))
```

Comment: Thank-you! With a little bit of finagling I was able to get this to pull what I was looking for. Here is the final query I have thanks to you. It is very much appreciated.

SELECT Tag, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM JodyTable 
WHERE Tag NOT IN ('ldnont', 'ldnon')
AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM JodyTable WHERE Tag IN ('ldnont', 'ldnon'))
GROUP BY Tag
ORDER BY cnt DESC

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly - you want to count how many records with the same id has either "ldnon" or "ldnont" tags in table, not counting "ldnon" and "ldnont" themselves

```
select outer.tag, count(*) as outer.num
from table as outer
where outer.tag NOT = "ldnon" AND outer.tag NOT = "ldnont"  
outer.id IN (
select * from table  as inner
where outer.id = inner.id AND
(inner.tag = "ldnon" OR onner.tag="ldnont")
)
group by outer.tag
order by outer.num
```

this one is quite complicated maybe, but straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the above answered seemed a little more straight forward. Would there be any speed benefit going with your answer VS Larry's?

Comment: it's the same, just few shortcuts used instead of explicit conditions list. enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select  t1.tag, count(*)
from table as t1, table as t2 
where 
t1.id = t2.id AND t1.tag NOT = t2.tag AND 
t1.tag NOT = "ldnon" AND t1.tag NOT = "ldnont" AND
(t2.tag = "ldnon" OR t2.tag = "ldonont")
group by t1.tag
```